# How can I use QtMultimedia on desktop apps?

Tags: qt, desktop-application, multimedia

I have built an app using Qt creator for symbiyan mobile; now, I am trying to convert it to a desktop app using Qt. But when I change the platform it shows a problem with `QtMultimedia`; more specifically, `QAudioInput` and `QAudioOutput`.

> error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QAudioOutput' with no type
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QAudioInput' with no type

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install the QtMultimedia module in your desktop? Do you have the headers? Do you have the libQtMultimedia.so library?

Comment: Yea, it is installed with Qt creator, this same code runs on symbian simulator and works well, but in desktop app it get this error...can u help?by the way thanks for the answer.

Comment: Did you #include <QAudioOutput>? Is Qt Creator finding it? Try to create a test source including that and just instantiating QAudioOutput using the same Qt installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And I have solved the problem. Thank you Luca for your help. Luca said to include QAudioOutput. But that was there always. I have told you earlier the app was first written for Symbian device. In symbian simulator the project file does not want the QtMultimedia declaration. But in the case of a desktop app it is important to write

```
QT += multimedia
```

then project can use QAudioInput or QAudioOutput.
Thanks Luca. Thanks all. My app now runs on the desktop environment.